# How to use tqdm with map for Dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tqdm

Can I use tqdm progress bar with map function to loop through dataframe/series rows?

specifically, for the following case:

```
def example(x):
    x = x + 2
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dframe = pd.DataFrame([{'a':1, 'b': 1}, {'a':2, 'b': 2}, {'a':3, 'b': 3}])
    dframe['b'] = dframe['b'].map(example)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Due to the integration of tqdm with pandas you can use `progress_map` function instead of `map` function.**

**Note**: for this to work you should add `tqdm.pandas()` line to your code.

**So try this:**

```
from tqdm import tqdm

def example(x):
    x = x + 2
    return x

tqdm.pandas()  # <- added this line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dframe = pd.DataFrame([{'a':1, 'b': 1}, {'a':2, 'b': 2}, {'a':3, 'b': 3}])
    dframe['b'] = dframe['b'].progress_map(example)  # <- progress_map here
```

**Here is the [documentation reference](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/#pandas-integration)**:

> (after adding `tqdm.pandas()`) ... you can use `progress_apply` instead of `apply` and `progress_map`
>   instead of `map`